# Apache SOLR sort order

Tags: magento, solr

I'm using apache solr search in shop based on magento enterprise.

I have some hard problem, and I can't solve it by myself. if some who have solr expirience please help me;)

Solr search is pretty good and it works fine, but I have issue about sorting search results.

I can explain it by example:

We search product by query ex. "HP-118",
and we receive response with ex. 40 products.
In this order "HP-118 LaserJet", "HP-118 DescJet", "HP-118 box case", "Simple thing for HP-118", "Another simple thing for HP-118", "HP-118 BoxJet" etc...

And my problem is in last product in example.
I need to see products that have search query at the begining together..

ex. "HP-118 LaserJet", "HP-118 DescJet", "HP-118 box case","HP-118 BoxJet", "Simple thing for HP-118", "Another simple thing for HP-118"

Thanks for any help !

Comment: dude you have the enterprise :) paying hard cash for support :) contact their support

Comment: and the fact you are a developer stops to utilize the paid support?

Comment: Magento Enterprise literally has no support. Support stops the moment you install any additional module OR have any less than documented installation server environment (which includes every install I can imagine after the first 5 minutes) .. it is a total let down. What you are paying for is some extra out of the box features which are pretty good, like full page caching and SOLR search. Other than that all you get is bug fix support and occasional version updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes to *score* value (unless you explicitly set other sort order). To check why your results are returned in this order you can do few things:

1. Read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ
2. Add score to returned fields, so you can see difference etc. (and *score* to fl parameters)
3. Turn on the debug mode in responces (add *&debugQuery=on* parameter to request)
4. Study the debug, it will tell you why given result is scored with the value X

I hope that you will find the answer in the debug.
There are ways to boost specific fields, but to help with this you would need to specify more info.